# Is there a way to create alias usernames on Github?

Tags: email, github, alias

Here's the problem. A long time ago my company switched from SVN to Github. At that time, they told me, "Just use your current github account" for which I had used my "hacker" name, you know like, "ColdRolledCode". I didn't really understand what was going on enough to have protested that. Over the years however it's real annoying at work to try and figure out people's employee names in commit logs etc. because everyone used their friggin' personal account names and are effectively invisible, anonymous non-persons company-wise.

I want to just have my REAL NAME displayed in commmits etc. But Github won't allow me to create another account tied to the same email address (I think the company Single Signon system uses my company email so I have to use that for my Github account)